# Hyper-V 2012R2 Private Vlans and Cisco Swith

Tags: cisco, hyper-v, vlan, pvlan

I have a trouble with configuration of Cisco Catalyst 3850 (WS-C3850-24T-E). Hyper-V server (2012R2) is connected to it. My issue is to separate the virtual machines on the Layer 2 Level. The virtual machines located in the same IP subnet.  I chose to use a private VLAN feature in a Hyper-V. I set PrimaryVlanId 100 -SecondaryVlanId 1-10 on the virtual machine network adapters. I have configured an access port with VLAN ID 100 on Cisco. But the virtual machines don’t work with private VLAN. Which configuration should I set on the Cisco side in order to get it works with the private VLAN VMs?

Answer (score 2):

Set the VLAN on the NIC in the VM settings in Hyper-V manager and set the switch port to mode trunk with at least that VLAN allowed.  Remember that you won't be able to route between VLANs with the same subnet on them, so you will need to change IP schemes if they need to communicate at layer 3 but be separated at layer 2.